# Pinia state initialized with async function but only after component is mounted

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, store, pinia

I'm using Pinia and Vue.js 3 to display a list of products in a page.
However, when I use my product store in my component, all I see in the page is **loading**. Only when I go to another pages and come back to the products page, is when I see that my products are gotten from the store and listed in the page. Which, I guess, it means that the component is mounted and everything before the store has initialized the state from the async function.

Here is the code:

**Pinia Store**

```
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { TProduct, TProductResponse } from "@types";

import { fetchData } from "@utils";

export const useProductsStore = defineStore("products", () => {
  const products = ref<TProduct[]>([]);

  async function setProducts() {
    products.value = (
      await fetchData<TProductResponse>(
        "https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=5"
      )
    ).products;
  }

  onMounted(async () => {
    await setProducts();
  });

  return {
    products,
  };
});
```

**Component**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

import { ProductCard } from "@components";

import { TProduct } from "@types";

import { useProductsStore } from "@stores";

const productsStore = useProductsStore();

const products = ref<TProduct[]>(productsStore.products);
</script>
```

Thank You!

Comment: "_all I see in the page is **loading**._"  What do you mean?  Show the relevant HTML/JS code for this loading state.  You need to include how loading state is both defined and used.  You will need to disable the loading state whenever the fetch is done. We can't give specific advice on how to do this not knowing anything about how your loading state works.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Concerning the loading thing, all I do is render a p tag showing the text "Loading..." if ```products.length === 0``` else I render the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to the store is being made on initial mount, but the DOM is not refreshing with the updated value because reactivity has been lost. The reason the store values appear after navigating away and back again is because these actions are forcing the DOM to refresh.

To maintain reactivity in your component you can directly use `productsStore.products` instead of making a new ref called `products`.  Or if you really want to deconstruct to a new variable you should use the [storeToRefs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Destructuring-from-a-Store) helper function.

```js
import { useProductsStore } from "@stores";
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const productsStore = useProductsStore()

const { products } = storeToRefs(productsStore)
```

I should also point out that, while it does work in your case, it's not best practice to [use onMounted hook inside a Pinia store](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1508).  Ideally, you should call the `setProducts` action from an actual component's onMounted hook.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @yoduh. It worked! And instead of using ```onMounted()``` hook inside the pinia store, i moved it to ```App.vue```.  However, i don't think this is a good practice. Imagine if we have many stores, and so asynchronously initialize all of their state at once inside ```App.vue``` is bad since we aren't sure that all of them will be used in the app by the end users. Do you have a better idea to implement this kind of things. Thanks once again!